# Javascript appendchild not including element in Body/Head

Tags: javascript

I am using code to add javascript to my page using javascript file..

My code is :

```
 alert("works");


   addScript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js');
   addScript('js/pdttrack/jquery.titlealert.js');
   addScript('js/pdttrack/jquery.msgbox.min.js');

  function addScript(filename) {
      var tagPosition = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
      var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
      scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
      scriptElement.setAttribute('src', filename);
      tagPosition.appendChild(scriptElement);
      alert("added "+ scriptElement);
  }
```

...but the last alert is not firing.. seems

```
tagPosition.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

is not firing rest all are..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
var tagPosition = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
```

To:

```
var tagPosition = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

Since `getElementsByTagName` returns `NodeList` which is `Array`-like and you need to specify `index/key` to the array.

**You can also simply do:**

```
var tagPosition = document.body;
```

**Learn more on MDN:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: Check out our timestamps. We answered at *exactly* the same time :)

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a *list* of elements with the given tag name. That list does not have a method called `appendChild`. You want to grab the *first* one and operate on that:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
```

More information:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName